# java enforcing the return type to generic types instead of Object types for constructing map using collectors and streams

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, collectors

I'm trying to construct `Map<String, GraphNode<Character>>` from `List<Pair<GraphNode<Character>, List<String>>>` pairs. But the problem i'm facing is that it is giving errors saying that *Type mismatch: cannot convert* from `Map<Object,Object>` to `Map<String,GraphNode<Character>>`.

How should i enforce to return `Map<String,GraphNode<Character>>`

```
List<Pair<GraphNode<Character>, List<String>>> pairs = lines.stream().map(line -> {
            String[] split = line.split(":");
            List<String> dest = Lists
                    .newArrayList(Splitter.on(",").trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().splitToList(split[1]));
            GraphNode<Character> node = new GraphNode<>(split[0].toCharArray()[0]);
            return new javafx.util.Pair<GraphNode<Character>, List<String>>(node, dest);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<String, GraphNode<Character>> graphMap = pairs.stream().map(pair -> pair.getKey())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(GraphNode::getData, pair -> pair));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your class has `Character` type (`GraphNode<Character>`) so I think `GraphNode::getData` also return `Character` related type.

But you assigned it to `String` in `Map<String, GraphNode<Character>>` so type mismatch occur.

The resolution is to map the `GraphNode::getData` to String

Answer (score 2):

Your `map` step is wrong, since you are discarding the data in the `List<String>` (the value part of the `Pair`s), which I'm assuming you wanted to be in the output map. I suggest using `flatMap` to transform the `Stream<Pair<GraphNode<Character>, List<String>>>` to a `Stream<Pair<GraphNode<Character>, ListString>>`. From there, getting a `Map<String, GraphNode<Character>>` is trivial.

```
Map<String, GraphNode<Character>> graphMap =
    pairs.stream()
         .flatMap(pair->pair.getValue().stream().map(s -> new javafx.util.Pair<GraphNode<Character>, String>(pair.getKey(), s)))
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getValue,Pair::getKey));
```